# Dependence of Skolem functions on existentially quantified variables

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

when skolemizing (like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form)) apparently we only take into account universally quantified variables, for example for the formula$\forall x\, \exists y : D(x,y)$ for some predicate $D$. If we skolemize this expression, we get $D\big(x,f(x)\big)$.
My question now is about what happens if we have multiple existentially quantified variables. For example this expression: $$\exists z \, \forall x \, \exists y : D(x,y,z) \,\,\xrightarrow{\text{Skolemizing}}\,\,D\big(x,f(x),z\big).$$Although $f$ should intuitively be a function of $x$ and $z$, if we follow the procedure described [here and in numerous other textbooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form), if is just a function depending on $x$, like in above's formula.
Why is that? Is it just clear to everybody that $f$ clearly depends on $z$ anyway, therefore we don't write it down?
Any explanation would be highly appreciated!

Comment: No, the leading existential quantifier asserts that ther is a $z$ such that; thus, call it $a$ and rewrite the formula as $\forall x \exists y D(x,y,a)$. Now, there is no more a "variable" $z$ and the new formula simply asserts that "for every $x$ there is an $y$ such that..."; now the choice of $y$ is not free but it depends of the value of $x$; this depedency is expressed through a function $f$ linking the two: $\exists f \forall x D(x, f(x), a)$.

Comment: I understand (I think), thank you!